# Define coloneq (def) with redefined \=

Tags: mathtools, definition

For my own convenience, I tried to define some short-cut key for ``define'' as

```
\usepackage{mathtools}

\NewCommandCopy{\tmp}{\=}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\=}{\ =\ }%
}
\def\:={\ \coloneqq\ }
\def\=:{\ \eqqcolon\ }
```

However, this does not give the satisfactory result:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{align*}
    f_Z(z) &\:= \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{XY}(x,z-x)dx   \\
    &\= \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)dx  \\
    &\=: (f_X * f_Y)(z),
\end{align*}
```

this gives wrong spacing for "\=:" while "\:=" is good.
[image]

Is there clever way to handle this?

I would be really appreciated if you let me know some trick or techniques.

Thanks,

Comment: Actually, the spacing is really not the best. How often do you use this notation? Is there really a need for the shorthand you propose? Since `\= ` wouldn't match `\=:` in the definition, you'll have to define `\=` to peek ahead and set an appropriately-spaced `:` or something else.

Comment: I very often use `\ = \ ` for spacing equations and `\ \coloneqq \ ` and `\ \eqqcolon \ ` for defining some mathematical objects. So defining commands `\=`, `\=:`, and `\=:` would be the best for both of simplicity and intuitiveness.

Comment: The spacing around a math relation `\coloneqq` or `\eqqcolon` is well-defined; using `\ \coloneqq\ ` or `\ \eqqcolon\ ` doesn't really provide appropriate spacing. I assume your use of the additional/surrounding spaces ``\ `` stems from using `eqnarray`?

Comment: Exactly! I want to use similar spacing of `eqnarray` by using `align`.

Comment: @SeungHyeonYu You're pretty much alone in wanting such excessive spacing.

Comment: don't use `\def` it lets you redefine core commands without warning. `\def\:=` redefines the space command `\:` ,`\def\=:` redefines `\=` but your redefine it again.  `eqnarray ` is deprecated as it inserts excessive space, `align` should be used with it normal space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to shoot yourself in the foot and succeed.

Redefining `\=` that way opens you to problems in case your document wants to use the original meaning (macron accent).

Second: your `\def\=:` doesn't define the control sequence `\=:` (which is impossible), but redefines `\=` to require `:` after it. However, this is overridden by the redefinition of the same `\=` you do at begin document.

You can use just `:=` and `=:` if you have many of these symbols<sup>1</sup>

About the additional spacing, sorry, but I can't help in getting bad output.<sup>2</sup>

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\renewcommand{\vcentcolon}{\mathrel{\mathop\standardcolon}}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Nn \seung_equals:
 {
  \peek_charcode_remove:NTF : { \eqqcolon } { \standardequal }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \seung_colon:
 {
  \peek_charcode_remove:NTF = { \coloneqq } { \standardcolon }
 }

\AtBeginDocument
 {
  \mathchardef\standardequal=\mathcode`=
  \mathchardef\standardcolon=\mathcode`:
  \char_set_active_eq:NN = \seung_equals:
  \char_set_active_eq:NN : \seung_colon:
  \mathcode`=="8000\scan_stop:
  \mathcode`:="8000\scan_stop:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    f_Z(z) &:= \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{XY}(x,z-x)\,dx   \\
    &= \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)\,dx  \\
    &=: (f_X * f_Y)(z),
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Footnotes**

1. I've never understood the need for ≔ or ≕.
2. The spacing around the relation symbol in `eqnarray` is widely considered typographically wrong. Compare and decide.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I understand that `eqnarray` is wrong format, but I would prefer more spacing around "main" relation, because it is much psychologically recognizable to distinguish how we deal some mathematical object (left) by decomposing it (right). Then I will just use `\ =\ `!